# jQuery Ajax Call returns error : ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

"HomeController.cs" - this is my controller class.
"ForgotPassword" - this is the action result method in the above class.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ForgotPassword(string EmailID)
    {
        SendMail(EmailID);
        return View();
    }
```

In SendMail() function, I am sending a verification link to the passing EmailID.
I am calling this method via jQuery Ajax Method like below:

```
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function (e) {

            var emailRegex = new RegExp(/^([\w\.\-]+)@@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$/i);
            //var emailRegex = new RegExp(/^([\w-\.]+)@@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/);
            var emailAddress = $("#txtEmail").val();
            //alert(emailAddress);
            var valid = emailRegex.test(emailAddress);
            if (!valid) {
                alert("Please Enter Valid Email address");
                return false;
            } else {
                alert(emailAddress);
                //return true;
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Content("~/Home/ForgotPassword")',
                    async: false,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ 'EmailID': emailAddress }),
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert("Error");
                        alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                        //$("#errMsg").css('background', 'red');
                        //$("#errMsg").html(data.Message);
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        //$("#errMsg").css('background', 'green');
                        //$("#errMsg").html("Mail Sent");
                        alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                    }

                });
            }
        });
```

This is my View:

```
  <input type="text" name="EmailID" id="txtEmail" width="600" />
  <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" value="Send" />
```

I am calling this method when button click of "btnSubmit".

Everything is working fine. The SendMail() function is called and the mail is also send to the passing mailid. But I am getting error in the jQuery Ajax.

```
  error: function (response) {
                        alert("Error");
                        alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                        //$("#errMsg").css('background', 'red');
                        //$("#errMsg").html(data.Message);
                    },
```

I want to display the successful message in the view. But getting error. What is actually the problem? How to solve this?

Comment: You specify `dataType: "json",` but your returning html (which needs to be a partial view, not a view) so you need to change it to `dataType: "html",` (or just omit it). You can also omit `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` and just use `data: { EmailID: emailAddress },`

Comment: @StephenMuecke : Thanks.. Your suggestion is worked..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you are returning a `View()` from the action. This is effectively html, which is not what jQuery expects and presumably not what you want.

If there is nothing to return, just 200 response for successful execution, return null or empty result:

```
return new EmptyResult();
```

Or, if there is some json to return, make sure to call it:

```
return Json(new {result="Success"});
```

Also, as a side note, your URL looks a bit weird. Make use of route resolution here:

```
url: '@Url.Action("ForgotPassword", "Home")'
```

Comment: I am executing the method. I want to show the success message in div tag.

Comment: getting compilation error :  'UrlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'ActionLink'

Comment: @thevan, yes, server-side method is called fine. The problem is that it returns ViewResult, which is html response, while jQuery expects json response (as set in `dataType` param). You need to decide on one or the other.

Comment: @thevan, sorry, that should be just `Url.Action`, amended